# how to fix output issue?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

So Basically my Code output is to prompt the user for the price of each car
and then save the input and do calucaltions using the following four functions in the code below. and then output the following for each car in the `display_total_Car_cost()` function for each car at the same time.

my problem is that my code prompts the user twice for each each price and then displays the following output for the all cars at the same time how i change my code so that it prompts the user for each car price once and then outputs the last functonion `display_total_car_cost()` for each car on a different line.
below is my code and i commented out the output so that you will see kind a visual of what my code is outputting.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include <iomanip>
float get_vehicle_price(string);
float calculate_other_costs(float);
float calculate_registration_fee(float);
void display_total_car_cost(string, float, float);
 int main() {
     ifstream myfile;
     string car;
     string car2;
     string car3;
     string car4;
     myfile.open("infile.txt");
     getline(myfile, car);
     getline(myfile, car2);
     getline(myfile, car3);
     getline(myfile, car4);
     get_vehicle_price(car);
     get_vehicle_price(car2);
     get_vehicle_price(car3);
     get_vehicle_price(car4);
     float price1 = get_vehicle_price(car);
     float price2 = get_vehicle_price(car2);
     float price3 = get_vehicle_price(car3);
     float price4 = get_vehicle_price(car4);
     float other_costs1 = calculate_other_costs(price1);
     float other_costs2 = calculate_other_costs(price2);
     float other_costs3 = calculate_other_costs(price3);
     float other_costs4 = calculate_other_costs(price4);
     string model1 = car;
     string model2 = car2;
     string model3 = car3;
     string model4 = car4;
     display_total_car_cost(model1, price1, other_costs1);
     display_total_car_cost(model2, price2, other_costs2);
     display_total_car_cost(model3, price3, other_costs3);
     display_total_car_cost(model3, price4, other_costs4);
     return 0;
}
float get_vehicle_price(string carname) {
    float carprice;
    cout << "Enter the price of the :" << carname;
    cin >> carprice;
    return carprice;
}
float calculate_other_costs(float price) {
    float salestax = price *0.06;
    float other_costs = salestax + calculate_registration_fee(price);
    return other_costs;
}
float calculate_registration_fee(float price) {
    const int administrative_fee = 240;
    const int cost_of_tags = 120;
    float registration_fee = (price *0.10) + administrative_fee + cost_of_tags;
    return registration_fee;
}
void display_total_car_cost(string models, float price, float other_cost){
    float totalcost = price + other_cost;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << models << setw(2) << setprecision(2) << price << setw(3) << setprecision(4) << other_cost << setw(4) << setprecision(2) << totalcost;

}
```

Comment: rather than `string model1`, `string model2`, etc... consider using an array: `string model[4];`

Answer (score -1):

The first four call to `get_vehicle_price()` are unusefull: you ask for a value that is lost. You can delete/comment they

```
 //get_vehicle_price(car);
 //get_vehicle_price(car2);
 //get_vehicle_price(car3);
 //get_vehicle_price(car4);
```

and maintain only the following usefull four calls

```
 float price1 = get_vehicle_price(car);
 float price2 = get_vehicle_price(car2);
 float price3 = get_vehicle_price(car3);
 float price4 = get_vehicle_price(car4);
```